# Netbeans call method in another class to set Jtextfield

Tags: java, forms, netbeans, methods

I'm trying to do as follows:

```
public void ProdutoEcontrado(String NomePro){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, NomePro);//
            jTextField2.setText(NomePro);
}
```

And another form:

```
public void EnviaValor(){
 Entrada EntradaForm =new Entrada();
 EntradaForm.ProdutoEcontrado(jList1.getSelectedValue());
}
```

In showMessageDialog the value appears but no in "settext()"